# sending httpResponse using printWriter

Tags: java, http, webserver, httpresponse, printwriter

I am trying to send an httpresponse using the printWriter, but all i get in the result is the status line without the entity. How can I send the whole response?

```
OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out));
writer.println(httpResponse.getStatusLine());
writer.println(httpResponse.getAllHeaders());
writer.println(httpResponse.getEntity());
writer.flush();
writer.close();
socket.close();
```

Comment: Can you show us what the raw response looks like? Try using something like Fiddler to view the request/response traffic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for me was to print the content of the response's entity line after line with a new empty line at the beggining of it.